# antlr4 does't parse obvious tree

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I want to create a Grammar that will parse the input statement

*myvar is 43+23*

and

*otherVar of myvar is "hallo"*

But the parser doesn't recognize anything here.
(sorry, I am not allowed to post images :( imagine a statement node with the Tokens 
[myvar] [is] [43] [+] [23] as children all marked red. Same goes for the other statement)

I'm getting error messages that confuse me:

*line 2:7 no viable alternative at input 'myvaris'*

*line 3:19 no viable alternative at input 'otherVarofmyvaris'*

Where are the spaces gone? I assume, It's something with my lexer, but I can't see what the problem is. Just in case here is the grammar for these statements:

```
statement
        : envCall                   #call_Environment_Function
        | identifier IS expression  # assignment_statement // This one should be used
        | loopHeader statement_block    # loop_statement
        etc... 

expression
    : '(' expression ')'                #bracket_Expression
    | mathExpression                    #math_Expression
    | identifier                        #identifier_Expression // this one should be used
    | objectExpression                  #object_Expression
    etc ...

identifier //both of these should be used
: selector=IDENTIFIER OF object=expression #ofIdentifier
| selector=IDENTIFIER #idLocal
;
```

here are all the Lexer rules I have so far:

```
IdentifierNamespace: IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER;
FromIn: FROM | IN;

OPENBLOCK: NEWLINE? '{';
CLOSEBLOCK: '}' NEWLINE;

NEWLINE: ['\n''\t']+;
NUMBER: INT | FLOAT;
INT: [0-9]+;
FLOAT: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;

IsAre: IS | ARE;

OF: 'of';
IS: 'is';
ARE: 'are';
DO: 'do';
FROM: 'from';
IN: 'in';
IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
//WHITESPACE: [ \t]+ -> skip;
fragment UNICODE : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX ;
fragment HEX : [0-9a-fA-F] ;
fragment ESC : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE) ;
STRING : '"' (ESC | ~["\\])* '"' ;
END: 'END'[.]* EOF;
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' )+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it. There was a compOP defined for the parser, and it was messing up the treegeneration.

```
compOP: '<'
  | '>'
  | '=' // the programmers '=='
  | '>='
  | '<='
  | '<>'
  | '!='
  | 'in'
  | 'not' 'in'
  | 'is' <- removed this one and it works now
  ;
```

So: never assign the same keyword to Parser and Lexer, I guess.